# Output CSV to array

Tags: php, csv, checkbox, meta-boxes

I am using WP Alchemy to create a meta box with multiple check boxes.

The trouble I'm having is, I have a csv list of academic courses that I want to create the check box options from. So I'm taking the csv turning it into an array that the boxes are made from. However with the code I have now, only the LAST line is created in the array.

```
<?php

$file_handle = fopen('curriculum.csv', 'r');

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

$line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
$parts = explode(',', $line_of_text);

$items = array ($parts[2] .$parts[3], );

}

fclose($file_handle);

?>

<?php foreach ($items as $i => $item): ?>

    <?php $mb->the_field('cb_ex3'); ?>

    <!-- similar to test #2, the same thing can be accomplished by simply
    adding array brackets "[]" to the name -->
    <input type="checkbox" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>[]" value="<?php echo $item; ?>"<?php $mb->the_checkbox_state($item); ?>/> <?php echo $item; ?><br/>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So out of the few hundred lines of code, all I get is the last line.
Here is the actually file I'm working with: http://www.ouhsd.k12.ca.us/educational_services/curriculum/curriculum.csv

Comment: 1. [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) 2. `$items[] = …`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the `fgetcsv()` ([docs](http://php.net/fgetcsv)) function rather than trying to make sense of the CSV data yourself.  Also, you should build the `$items` array (rather than overwriting it) as you loop over the file, adding a new item each time.

```
$file_handle = fopen('curriculum.csv', 'r');
fgets($file_handle); // this skips the csv header line
while (($parts = fgetcsv($file_handle)) !== FALSE) {
    $items[] = $parts[2] . ' ' . $parts[3];
}
fclose($file_handle);

foreach ($items as $item) {
    // Your HTML code goes here
    echo $item . PHP_EOL;
}
```

---

Bonus points (you'll look cooler, using objects and iterators!)

```
$file = new SplFileObject('curriculum.csv');
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
foreach (new LimitIterator($file, 1) as $parts) {
    $items[] = $parts[2] . ' ' . $parts[3];
}

foreach ($items as $item) {
    // Your HTML code goes here
    echo $item . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: You are a genius and a Saint! It worked!!! :) The only thing I chaged was the <code>echo $item . PHP_EQL;</code> because it was printing everything out on top of the checkboxes. HUGS!!

Answer (score 4):

In each iteration of the loop you replace $items when you want to add to it, thus it only having the last value.

Also http://php.net/fgetcsv might be of some use to you.

Comment: +1 beat me to it. fgetcsv is a great approach to handling CSV in PHP.

Comment: I figured it was looping through but not keeping anything. Any idea on how to to make it fgetcsv and keep the explode array? Everything I try leaves me with one blank checkbox. :(

Comment: +1 for fgetcsv. @OUHSD Webmaster: I'd also like to add (for future reference) that `$items` would be `$items[]` when you want to add something to an array. But in this case, definitely go with fgetcsv.

Answer (score 0):

items should be an array in your case. Initialize it outside the while loop

```
$items = array();
```

And then inside the while loop

```
$items[] = array ($parts[2] .$parts[3], );
```

should work.

Also look at fgetcsv as well as suggested.

Comment: When I try this and changing "fgets" to fgetcsv" I get a few hundred check boxes with the word Array accompanying each. I think there is one for each line of the CSV so maybe I'm closer?

Comment: have you looked at the fgetcsv documnetation?

Answer (score 0):

You need an extra dimenson to your array.

```
$i=0;
$items= new array(); // i think you need this for some fun reason
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    $parts = explode(',', $line_of_text);

    $items[$i] = array ($parts[2] .$parts[3], );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the `$items` array. I would like to suggest a much simpler method to

```
<code><pre><?php

    // in one step, load the datafile as an array, and loop over each line
    // then explode the line by comma, and add to $lines array
    foreach(file('curriculum.csv') as $line)
            $lines[] = explode(',',$line);

    // display the structure of the captured data
    print_r($lines);

?></pre></code>
```

I think once you understand the structure of the captured data here, you can use the values as you wish in your output loop.

`code`, `pre` and `php` tags added for convenience